# How to configure a clickable "WebView" that displays an image?

Tags: java, android, xml, webview, android-linearlayout

I created in Android Studio, a Layout which display `CardView`, and in each `CardView` there are a `TextView` widget and a `WebView` widget.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="280dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_id"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/card_web_id"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_title_id"
        android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Title"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I tried to add a listenner to the LinearLayout and the CardView.

```
holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,Film_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", mData.get(position).getUrlPic_Poster());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

At the end, if I click on the web view (which is only a image) nothing happen, I have to click on the text or on the border of the Layout to launch the new activity.

I would like that anytouch on the cardView launch the new activity, so I have to make clickable the Webview, but it doesn't work for me.

I've got some settings for the web view;

```
String html = "<html><body><img src=\"" + mData.get(position).getUrlPic_Poster() + "\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"\"/> 
</body></html>";
    holder.webView.loadData(html, "text/html", null);
    holder.webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    holder.webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    holder.webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    holder.webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    holder.webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    holder.webView.setFocusable(false);
    holder.webView.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: `setClickable(false)` make your `WebView` not clickable, and I think you should try `setOnTouchListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`